# Реализовать список

Tags: html, css, веб-программирование, html5, list

Помогите реализовать такой список. Кучу вариантов перепробовал - не получается.

[image: список]

Разметка:

```
<div id="menubar">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum ne</a><span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">About us</a><span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Eventos</a><span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Ipsum Dolor</a><span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Noticias</a><span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span></li>
        <li><a href="#">Pro nihil sumo</a><span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Стили:

```
#menubar ul li{
    display: inline;
    font: 24px Gothic,Arial sans-serif;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
    border-right: 5px solid #eee;
}

#menubar ul li:last-child{
    padding-right: 0;
    border: none;
}

#menubar ul li:first-child{
    padding-left: 0;
}

#menubar ul li a{
    color: #0a8ca3;
    display: block;
    float: left;
}

#menubar-sub {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    font: 12px Arial sans-serif;
    padding-right: 15px;
    padding-left: 15px;
}
```

Comment: покажите вариант, который не получается

Comment: пробовал много вариантов, один из последних добавил

Comment: вот приблизительный вариант - http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/9tosLjqf/

Comment: отлично, а что конкретно не получается?

Comment: Проблема решена. soledar10, Большое спасибо!

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
nav {
  text-align: center;  
}

nav ul {
  background: silver;
  display: inline;
  font-size: 37px;
  padding: 0;
}

nav li {
  display: inline-block;
  font: 24px Gothic, Arial sans-serif;
  padding: 0 15px;
  background: white;
  height: 42px;
  vertical-align: top;
  text-align: left;
}

nav a, nav .menubar-sub {
  display: block;
}

nav .menubar-sub {
  font: 12px Arial sans-serif;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum ne</a><span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">About us</a><span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Eventos</a><span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Ipsum Dolor</a><span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Noticias</a><span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span></li>
    <li><a href="#">Pro nihil sumo</a><span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span></li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ответ из комментария.

---

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", sans-serif;
}
#menubar {} #menubar > ul {
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 0;
  margin: 25px auto;
}
#menubar > ul > li {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
  padding: 0 25px;
  text-align: left;
  position: relative;
  margin: 5px 0;
}
#menubar > ul > li:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 5px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #777;
}
#menubar > ul > li:first-child:before {
  background: none;
}
#menubar > ul > li a {
  display: block;
  color: #007E97;
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 700;
  text-decoration: none;
}
#menubar > ul > li a > span {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 400;
  color: #777;
}
#menubar > ul > li:hover a {
  color: #f00;
}
#menubar > ul > li:hover a > span {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
```

```html
<nav id="menubar">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">Lorem ipsum ne
            <span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span>
            </a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About us
             <span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span>
            </a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Noticias
            <span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span>
            </a> 
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">Pro nihil sumo
            <span class="menubar-sub">Lorem Ipsum Dolor</span>
            </a> 
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```