# Создать шрифт с пробелом нужной ширины

Tags: css, веб-программирование, шрифты, кроссбраузерность

Хочу создать иконочный шрифт с единственным символом - пробелом (обычным, 0x20). У пробела должна быть фиксированная ширина, в идеале, не зависящая от размера шрифта. Ширина именно заданная, т. е. не обязательно нулевая.

- Реально ли это в плане кроссбраузерности?
  Точнее, все ли требуемые форматы шрифтов позволят сделать не зависящую от размера ширину?
- Какие сервисы или программы можно для этого использовать?
  И что требуется для получения шрифта?
  Например, достаточно ли пустой svg-картинки с нужными размерами?
- Возможно, есть какие-то альтернативы?
  Мысли крутятся вокруг `word-spacing` и `letter-spacing`, но я помню, что там что-то не то у разных браузеров при совмещении с inline-блоками. К тому же, `word-spacing` считается относительно текущей ширины пробела, что в данном случае не очень хорошо.

Comment: а можно узнать? зачем?

Comment: @xaja, я думал, из вопроса понятно. Просто несколько тем про меню натолкнули на эту идею. У браузера есть особые правила отображения пробелов в inline-элементах при переносе текста не следующую строку. Кстати, с типографскими пробелами это не слишком-то работает. Вот и возникла мысль, а что если создать специальный шрифт из единственного пробела.

Comment: Сегодня - [это этот вопрос](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/452129/178988), а некоторое время назад был похожий, где спрашивалось, как сделать, чтобы при переносе меню на следующую строку разделительной линии в конце/начале строки не было. [Вариант с пробелом](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/452541/178988) вроде бы является решением, но контроль за шириной разделителя весьма сомнителен, а вот при специальном шрифте всё было бы хорошо. Кстати, я тут подумал, возможно имеет смысл иметь не прозрачный пробел, а закрашенный. Хотя не факт - тут скорее поэкспериментировать надо.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20473553/4928642